# Maintain files selection using Intent.createChooser

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-intent-chooser

I'm using following code to select one or more files in Android from gallery:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("video/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);


imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select files"), 1);
    }
});
```

This code works ok, I'm to able to select one or more files.

The problem is when I press **again** `imgBtn`, user can't see what was  previous selected in `chooser` screen.

Is there a way to **maintain** **files selection** when user clicks the button again?

[image]

Comment: "user needs to re-select previous selected files" -- why?

Comment: Thanks, question edited